# Sourcetree 1.8.3 Crashes when login at first after install

Tags: git, crash, bitbucket, sourcetree

I have installed source tree v1.8.3 and when I login to my Alassian account at first to complete installation, the source tree crashes.
My OS is win 8.1.
[image]

Sourcetree log file is here:

> ERROR [2016-07-11 12:13:15,043] [PriorityScheduler: ] [SourceTree.Bookmarks.BookmarkManager] [RegisterBookmarkEventHandlers] - RegisterBookmarkEventHandlers called with null list

How can I solve it?

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that source tree use IE for login. On win 8.1 it has occur some issues. I am not sure why it have. You can follow steps.

1. Install sourcetree.exe
2. After installing, login Atlassian account.
3. If crash the app, accounts.json file to C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\
   And replace Username with your account name in accounts.json file.
4. You can use source tree application logged in with your account.

accounts.json file is

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "SourceTree.Api.Host.Identity.Model.IdentityAccount, SourceTree.Api.Host.Identity",
    "Authenticate": true,
    "HostInstance": {
      "$id": "2",
      "$type": "SourceTree.Host.Atlassianaccount.AtlassianAccountInstance, SourceTree.Host.AtlassianAccount",
      "Host": {
        "$id": "3",
        "$type": "SourceTree.Host.Atlassianaccount.AtlassianAccountHost, SourceTree.Host.AtlassianAccount",
        "Id": "atlassian account"
      },
      "BaseUrl": "https://id.atlassian.com/"
    },
    "Credentials": {
      "$id": "4",
      "$type": "SourceTree.Model.BasicAuthCredentials, SourceTree.Api.Account",
      "Username": "<Atlassianaccount>",
      "Email": null
    },
    "IsDefault": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this error is that the **user.config** file for SourceTree has been corrupted.

You can confirm this by locating the file in this location:

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_<random_string>\<version_number>
```

If this is the cause, when you open the file, it will be full of  values.

Solution is by deleting the **user.config**